# discord.js Message bulk delete only deleteing the limit and not what is specified

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

So I am trying to get the bot to delete the specified amount and not the limit, The limit being the maximum amount I want to be deleted when specified by it only deletes the limit amount. I've tried a couple of thing but to no avail.

```
async run(message, args) {
    var obliviateRoles = [
        'Dev',
        'Bot Dev',
        'Moderator'
    ]
    var hasRole = false;
    obliviateRoles.forEach(findrole =>{
        if(message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === findrole)) hasRole = true; //if user has role, sets bool to true
    })
    var mention = message.mentions.users.first()

    if(hasRole === true){
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
// Parse Amount
const amount = !!parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) ? parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) : parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[2])

if (!amount) return message.reply('Must specify an amount to delete!');

if (!amount && !user) return message.reply('Must specify a user and amount!');
// Fetch 100 messages (will be filtered and lowered up to max amount requested)
message.channel.messages.fetch({
    limit: 5,
   }).then((messages) => {
 if (user) {
 const filterBy = user ? user.id : Client.user.id;
 
messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === filterBy).array().slice(0, amount);
 }
 message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
});
}else{
    message.reply('This Spell is too powerful for you.')

  }
 }
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: So let me try to understand, you  want to delete an amount of messages but the maximum amount is 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing `messages` to [bulkDelete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) you're deleting every message in the channel because `channel.fetch()` returns the entirety of a text channels messages. [bulkDelete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) does accept a numerical value. So where n is equal to an non-negative integer, you can call `channel.bulkDelete(n)`.

e.g

```
var num = 15 // whatever number you want
message.channel.bulkDelete(num).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if that helps you(I improved your code a little bit)

```js
async run(message, args) {
if(['Dev','Bot Dev','Moderator'].some((r) => message.member.roles.cache.has(role => role.name == r))){
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
// Parse Amount
const amount = !!parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) ? parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[1]) : parseInt(message.content.split(' ')[2])

if (!amount) return message.reply('Must specify an amount to delete!');

if (!amount && !user) return message.reply('Must specify a user and amount!');
// Fetch 100 messages (will be filtered and lowered up to max amount requested)
message.channel.messages.fetch({
    limit: amount > 5 ? 5 : amount,
   }).then((messages) => {
messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === user.id).array();
message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
});
}else{
    message.reply('This Spell is too powerful for you.')
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: that bugs the }else{ function